# What is the best way to separate UI (designer/editor) logic from the Package framework (like Visual Studio Package)

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, vsx

I want to separate concerns here. Create and embed all the UI logic for the Custom XML designer, object model, validations etc in to a separate assembly. Then the Package framework should only register the designer information and ask for a UI Service and everything works magically.

This way I don't need to play with the Package framework (Visual Studio Package) assembly, when I need to modify the UI designer.

This question also applies to anything where you have to separate the UI logic from the Skeleton framework that loads it up, like a plugin.

I have several choices a ServiceProvider model, a plugin model or may be other.

Any samples, suggestions for patterns, links are welcome.

Update 1: What I am looking for is a thought such as - "Does Prism (Composite WPF) fit the bill? Has anyone worked on a project/application which does the separation of concerns just like I mentioned above? etc" 
(I am still looking out for answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a VSPackage that loads an editor. The Editor sits in a separate assembly and implements an interface that I defined. The VSPackage works with the interface, so any changes I make to the editor (and its assembly) does not affect the VSPackage as long as I don't change the interface.

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing. We also created a PackageSupport project that has these interfaces and common VS related logic and it's handy.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about seams very much like the separation of concerns that the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller) pattern tries to enforce.

[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) is already out there with a [preview 5](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16775).

It's mainly for web but I think they are planning on using it also for WinForms, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but I was looking for more precise suggestions/samples of having this done in relation to VSX package.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the [Model View Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx#S1) pattern